# Get a set of values from enum where item returns object

Tags: java, java-8

I have a `Manufacture` class:

```
public class Manufacture {

   private String businessId;

   //Getter & Setter
   ...
}
```

Then, I have an `enum` named `Product`, each item override its abstract method which returns a `Manufacture` instance:

```
public enum Product {
     FOO {
       @Override
       Manufacture getManufacture(){
            return // a instance of Manufacture
       }
     }

     BAR {
       @Override
       Manufacture getManufacture(){
            return // another instance of Manufacture
       }
     }

    abstract Manufacture getManufacture();
}
```

I get a `Set<Manufacture>` of manufacture from the `Product` enum by:

```
Set<Manufacture> manufactureSet = Stream.of(Product.values()).map(Product::getManufacture).collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

But if I want to get a `Set<String>` of `businessId` string from a static function inside `Product`, how to do ?

I was thinking:

```
 Set<String> businessIdSet = Stream.of(Product.values()).map(Product::getManufacture::getBusinessId).collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

But method reference in steam `.map(...)` can't be chained.

Comment: when you already know what a `map` is just chain the getters as `.map(product -> product.getManufacture().getBusinessId())` for which you need to use *lambda* instead of *method references*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain map calls, for example:

```
    Set<String> businessIdSet = Stream.of(Product.values())
            .map(Product::getManufacture)
            .map(Manufacture::getBusinessId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel mentioned you can chain map methods
or same can be achieved with lambda in single map

```
Set<String> businessIdSet = Stream.of(Product.values())
            .map(p-> p.getManufacture().getBusinessId())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```